# How to make a short running author list?

Tags: titles, amsart

I am writing a paper (using the amsart class) where we have four authors. The problem is that the author names on the even pages spill over onto the page numbers and obscure them. What I'd like to do is to define a short running author list (where, say, given names could be replaced by initials) and have it placed on top of the even pages.

But how does one do that within amsart?

Answer (score 10):

It should just work to write

```
\author[short name]{long name}
```

for each author in the preamble.

For example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\title{Of Cabbages and Kings}
\author[Y.X.H.A.E.A.W.K. Conley]{Yo Xing Heyno Augustus Eisner Alexander Weiser Knuckles Conley}
\address{New York University}
\author[N.I. Lobachevski]{Nicolai Ivanovich Lobachevski}
\address{Kazan University}
\author[J.J.J. Schmidt]{John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt}
\address{Hisnameismyname U.}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for dummy text

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-100]

\end{document}
```

Comment: But what about the affiliations? This solution requires me to do dagger, doesn't it?

Comment: @Felix: How do you normally do affiliations?  I think the `amsart` way is to have multiple `\address` declarations after the `\author` declaration, and they appear at the end of the article.

Comment: I write a separate \author and \address for each one. Perhaps it is not the smartest way....

Comment: @FelixGoldberg -- if you are using `amsart`, writing a separate `\author` and `\address` for each one is the *correct* way to do it.  this is different from the `article` class.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: thanks for that information.  I've updated my answer to the correct way.

Comment: How about multi-authors share the same address, but one of them have other address? How about department?

Comment: @MartinWang: In many journals if two of three authors share an address the address is listed twice.

Answer (score 8):

From page 12, section 4.3 of the [class documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/amscls-doc/Author_Handbook_Journals.pdf):

> If the author name(s) cannot fit in the space available for the running
> head, enter a shortened form for each name in [brackets] between the
> tag `\author` and the full name. Acceptable shortened forms use initials
> for all but the surname(s). For example,
>
> ```
> \author[J. Smith]{Joseph Smith}
> ```
>
> If the list of shortened author names is still too long for the
> running head (including a reasonable space for the page number), it
> can be shortened for an article in the following example:
>
> ```
> \author[J. Smith et al.]{Joseph Smith}  
> ...  
> \author[]{⟨second name⟩}
> ...  
> \author[]{⟨final name⟩}
> ```